# Effective way to compare database values and expected value

Tags: java, selenium, jdbc

I am using keyword driven framework using excel sheet as test data source.I want to compare database and excepted values for more than 20 SQL queries with different columns and tables.Currently i wrote one keyword for each SQL query. I am looking for more effective way to compare values with reusable assertion function.Currently my code looks like:

```
public compare_customer_details{
SQL1="select column1, column2...column10 from table A;
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(SQL1);
 while (rs.next()) {
firstname= rs.getString("a.given_name");
Lastname=rs.getString("a.surname");
dob=rs.getString("a.birthdate");
 if(Lastname.equalsIgnoreCase(GetDataFromExcel("LastName"))) {}
...}
```

Keyword 2- for different keyword:

```
public compare_Address_details{
SQL2="select column1, column2...column10 from table B;
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(SQL2);
 while (rs.next()) {
abc= rs.getString("a.abc");
Lastname=rs.getString("a.cde");
 if(abc.equalsIgnoreCase(GetDataFromExcel("abc"))) {}
...}
```

Please suggest effective ways.Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Selenium, and a test's expected result is presumably in the Excel data, why are you querying the db instead of getting the actual result from the UI with Selenium ?

Comment: db and selenium? Something does not sound right here!

Comment: I have to check in database as well. Framework  is in java and uses apis like selenium,sikuli,rest assure.For database connectivity  i am using jdbc driver.please let me know if require further info.

Comment: Try looking in to [dbunit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) - it may make your life a bit easier.

Comment: @Mureinik -does dbunit support unified database also?

Comment: i am still seeking for help